# How to convert multiple arrays into separate key and values

Tags: arrays, laravel

I want to convert the foillwing array into separate array of keys and separate array of values $products_selected_leeds returns the follwing array whereas i only need the keys in a array

```
$products_selected_leeds = DB::table('Products_selected_leeds')->select('product_id')->whereIn('leed_id',$where_in)->get();

dd($products_selected_leeds);

array:42 [
  0 => {#903
    +"product_id": 152
  }
  1 => {#904
    +"product_id": 756
  }
  2 => {#905
    +"product_id": 938
  }
  3 => {#906
    +"product_id": 172
  }
  4 => {#907
    +"product_id": 1200
  }
  5 => {#908
    +"product_id": 751
  }
  6 => {#909
    +"product_id": 753
  }
  7 => {#910
    +"product_id": 754
  }
  8 => {#911
    +"product_id": 755
  }
```

expected results

```
product_id =  [152 756,938,172,1200,751,753,754,755]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As You said to get all the ids to single array

```
$query = DB::table('Products_selected_leeds')
                ->select('product_id')
                ->whereIn('leed_id',$where_in)
                ->get()
                ->pluck('product_id')
                ->toArray();
```

And `dd($query)`

**EDITED FOR THE LARAVEL VERSON (`BELOW 5.3`)WHICH DOESN'T RETURN THE COLLECTION INSTANCE ON THE QUERY BUILDER**

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/10552

```
    $query = DB::table('Products_selected_leeds')
            ->select('product_id')
            ->whereIn('leed_id',$where_in)
            ->get();               

    $toCollection = collect($query);

    $arrayOfIds = $toCollection->pluck('product_id')->toArray();

    dd($arrayOfIds);
```

Kindly Comment Below if there is any issues or MARK MY Answer as ACCEPTED IF Is is Working fine

Comment: there's an error ` Call to a member function pluck() on array`

Comment: yes i copied the entire code what i am getting from this single query

Comment: Laravel Version please

Comment: 5.1 version of laravel

Comment: Check Now i have Updated my answer

Comment: Still error  ` Call to a member function toArray() on array `

Comment: i was looking into the code repo and found  that oly form  `Laravel 5.3` The Query Bilder is Returing the New Collection Object

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work

```
$products_selected_leeds = DB::table('Products_selected_leeds')->select('product_id')->whereIn('leed_id',$where_in)->pluck('product_id')->toArray();
```

Comment: it will return collection not the array he is looking for

Answer (score 0):

You must be use -`>pluck()` method

```
$products_selected_leeds->pluck('product_id')->toArray();
```

Or you can use

```
DB::table('Products_selected_leeds')->whereIn('leed_id',$where_in)->pluck('product_id')->toArray();
```

Comment: it is showing error `Call to a member function toArray() on integer`